# No connections being shown on wireless BCM43228 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, broadcom

Last night all network connections disappeared. It had been working up until then perfectly fine.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
```

Shows

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [8086:1502] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Dell 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [1028:0493]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 04)
--03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1530 Half-size Mini PCIe Card [1028:0011]
Kernel driver in use: wl
Kernel modules: bcma, wl

0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

The command:

```
lspci -nn -d 14e4:
```

shows

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
```

Dell Latitude E6420

- 3.7 GiB
- Intel® Core™ i7-2760QM CPU @ 2.40GHz × 8
- NVS 4200M/PCIe/SSE2

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Drivers look OK. Run `sudo systemctl restart network-manager`

Comment: Command ran, unfortunately no change

Answer (score 4):

I have the same configuration and I found solution

(if you already know you have BCM43228 than skip next line)

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

than install drivers (you have to connect to internet via Ethernet cable or Bluetooth)

```
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

restart network manager

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

now you have wifi card installed and can connect to internet with wifi :)

Answer (score 2):

Even though the wireless card still worked in Windows 10 so this shouldn't have been the problem it did solve it.

Full shutdown of laptop, removal of the battery and power cable then depressing the power button down for 15 seconds to drain all the caps.

Came right back to life. Not (but still maybe) a driver issue...

Just glad to have Linux back so I can use my computer instead of my Operating System............ Preparing your computer........... Please wait nine million years

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/854783)

Comment: @waltinator This is the OP describing how they solved their problem. It is an answer.

Comment: @Thomas see above

Comment: I would just like to say today I had the same problem searched online for a solution to no avail remembered this post and tried the same "Full shutdown of laptop, removal of the battery and power cable then depressing the power button down for 15 seconds to drain all the caps." and it worked a second time.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with my HP Elitebook 740 G2. Turns out it needed a BIOS update to current version and the issue resolved immediately.