# Ubuntu 19.10 | wifi keeps asking for password but doesn't connect | installed on MacBook Pro 2015

Tags: networking, wireless, macbook, macbook-pro

as mentioned in the title, I wiped my MacBook Pro 13 inches 2015 and installed ubuntu 19.10.

However, I can't connect to any wifi, I tried 3 different ones.

It keeps asking me for the password and not connect.

Please don't consider this as duplicate, as I have been trying all the different solutions posted before with no luck...

Here's the output after running `lspci -nn |grep 0280`

`03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)`

**UPDATE**

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and the problem is still there.

**UPDATE**

It just worked with another wifi network, apparently, the problem was with the previous modems configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with laptops with broadcomm wifi adapters and the following helped me:

My issues were a bit different though. I was using Ubuntu 18 LTS and while I did do a few macbooks I dont think I had that issue with them.  Also, in my case the networks were not visible...but you could have a driver compatibility issue that could be improved by a new/different driver.

linux ubuntu broadcomm drivers wifi
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)
[No connections being shown on wireless BCM43228 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052187/no-connections-being-shown-on-wireless-bcm43228-18-04)
[Ubuntu 18.04 No WiFi adapter found [Dell Inspiron 3542.]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061539/ubuntu-18-04-no-wifi-adapter-found-dell-inspiron-3542)